# Create a dashboard in Dynatrace Appmon web showing a set of purepaths/web requests

Tags: performance, metrics, dynatrace, apm

I want to create a dashboard with 1 tile showing a set of purepaths/web requests related to some web application flows that I'm interested in (like product search request, add product to basket etc.). Basically, I'm interested in "response time" of these bunch of purepaths/web requests so that I can track regularly if any purepath can be optimized! How can I create the same in Dynatrace Appmon web? The Dynatrace Appmon installed on server is version# 7.0.9.1019.

Answer (score 0):

Only way you can get PurePath response time in the Web based Dashboard Tile is using a Measure.

you can create a Business Transactions filtered by the URL like below. This will become a measure. ensure you check the box "Store results in Performance warehouse".

[image]

Once you do this in the thick client, In the web based application, edit tile, select measure, this new business transaction should appear.